# How to count 'li' elements and assert their number with Selenium and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to count 'li' elements in 'ul'. I want to assert that these elements are equal to a certain number.

```js
it('Check numbers of slick buttons', async function () {
    var list = Document.getElementsByClassName("slick-dots");
    console.log(list.children.lenght);
    assert.strictEqual(11, list.children.length);
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. You have a typo error "lenght" should be "length".

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and then using just the length of that list like so:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
assert.strictEqual(11, li.length);
```

if you want just the elements with a certain class then you should pass the class to the

Comment: Hi. You have a typo error "lenght" should be "length".